# Copying cell text to another worksheet if it is not a duplicate value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I have an array of data, e.g. `new_price = [{"a": 1.5}, {"b": 2.1}, {"c": 3.6}]`

I have two sheets with existing data, e.g.:

```
Sheet A  
item    old_price  
 a      1
 b      2
 c      3.1   

Sheet B  
item    new_price  
 c      3.6
```

How can i write a code that if an item's `new_price` (from the data array) is higher than the item's `old_price` (in sheet A) by 20% or more, and the item is not already on Sheet B, then copy the item to sheet B?

the output should be:

```
Sheet B  
item    new_price  
 c      3.6  
 a      1.5
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? As written this question is a bit too broad.

Comment: Exactly as you say. The simplest solution checks each array each time. The smarter solution builds a map object to reduce search time, but still requires an array loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('MyTools')
  .addItem('Update Price Data', 'updatePrice')
  .addToUi();
}

function updatePrice(){
  var ss1=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss1.getSheetByName('Items');
  var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SS2_ID');
  var sh2=ss2.getSheetByName('Items');
  var rg1=sh1.getDataRange();
  var vA1=rg1.getValues();
  var rg2=sh2.getDataRange();
  var vA2=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<vA1.length;i++){
    var ss2Contains=[];
    //if Item columnA in vA2 matches columnA in vA1 then update price
    for(var j=1;j<vA2.length;j++){
      ss2Contains.push(vA2[j][0]);
      if(vA1[i][0]==vA2[j][0] && vA1[i][2]!=vA2[j][2]){
        vA2[j][2]=vA1[i][2]
      }
    }
    //if columnA in vA1 is not found in vA2 then append it
    if(ss2Contains.indexOf(vA1[i][0])==-1){ 
       sh2.appendRow(vA1[i]);
     }
  }
  rg2.setValues(vA2);//update values in rg2
}
```

**Spreadsheet SS1**

[image]

**Spreadsheet SS2**

[image]

**Spreadsheet SS2 after update**

[image]